Every swap create a new account
In raydium sdk at each swap an account is created according to the instruction (the instruction is in the sdk itself, which must be changed somehow) and deleted.
How to create an account only once and then each swap was done without this action.
const { execute } = await raydium.liquidity.swap({
  poolInfo,
  poolKeys,
  amountIn: new BN(amount),
  amountOut: out.minAmountOut,
  fixedSide: 'in',
  inputMint: mintIn.address,
  txVersion,
  config: {
    inputUseSolBalance: isInputSol,
    outputUseSolBalance: isOutputSol,
    associatedOnly: false,
  },
});
// ...
const { txId } = await execute({ sendAndConfirm: false, skipPreflight: false });

